# acos does not give the value of the angle?

Tags: java, android

I have a program, which has a value for cosine. I want this value to be used in order to find the angle, which it corresponds to. However, acos does not actually give me a value for an angle (arcos normally works like that). Instead I get this (see below). Why is this happening, does acos work like that?

```
                double r,cos,sin,angVal;
                String temp = real.getText().toString();
                double a = Double.parseDouble(temp);
                temp=imag.getText().toString();
                double b =Double.parseDouble(temp);
                r=Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b);
                cos = a/r;
                sin = b/r;
                angVal = Math.acos(cos);
                ans.setText("r = "+r+"\ncos = "+cos+"\nsin = "+sin+"\nThe angle = "+angVal+"");
```

[image]

Comment: Please just type in the output next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [`Math.acos()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html#acos%28double%29) gives the angle, but in `radians` (i.e. in the range `[0..pi]`).

To convert it to degrees, use:

```
angVal = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(cos));
```